# PHP Singleton design PDO

Tags: php, pdo, singleton, php-7

I have been using singleton design for PDO on my websites for years with PHP5.
I am now migrating to PHP7 and I am seeing errors in my apache log file:

```
PHP Notice:  Accessing static property Db::$PDOInstances as non static in /var/www/class/class_db_test.php on line 12
PHP Notice:  Accessing static property Db::$PDOInstances as non static in /var/www/class/class_db_test.php on line 13
PHP Notice:  Accessing static property Db::$PDOInstances as non static in /var/www/class/class_db_test.php on line 32
```

Here is my Singleton class for DB access:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../setting.php");

class Db {
    private static $debug = 1;
    private static $debugPath = "/tmp/sql_debug.log";
    private static $PDOInstances = array("db1"=>"","db2"=>"");

    private function __construct($db_type){
        switch($db_type) {
            case "db1":
                $this->PDOInstances[$db_type] = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST,DB_USER ,DB_PWD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
                $this->PDOInstances[$db_type]->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            break;
            case "db2":
                $this->PDOInstances[$db_type] = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DB2_NAME.';host='.DB2_HOST,DB2_USER ,DB2_PWD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
                $this->PDOInstances[$db_type]->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            break;
        }
    }
    public static function getInstance($db_type) {
        if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("connection","");}

        if(self::$PDOInstances[$db_type] == null){
            self::$PDOInstances[$db_type] = new self($db_type);
        }
        return self::$PDOInstances[$db_type];
    }

    public function query($db_type,$query){
        if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("read request",$query);}
        return $this->PDOInstances[$db_type]->query($query);
    }

    public function exec($db_type,$query){
        if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("request",$query);}  
        return $this->PDOInstances[$db_type]->exec($query);
    }

    public function lastInsertId($db_type){
        return $this->PDOInstances[$db_type]->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function quote($db_type,$string){
        if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("quote",$string);} 
        return $this->PDOInstances[$db_type]->quote($string);
    }

    public static function sqlDebug($_mode,$_query){
        $today = date("m.d.y-H:m:s"); 
        if($_mode == "connection"){
            $line = $today." Connection: '".$_query."'\r\n";
        }
        else if($_mode == "quote"){
            $line = $today." Quote : '".$_query."'\r\n";
        }
        else if($_mode == "request"){
            $line = $today." Request : '".$_query."'\r\n";
        }
        else if($_mode == "read request"){
            $line = $today." Read request : '".$_query."'\r\n";
        }

        $file_debug = fopen(self::$debugPath, "a+");
        fwrite($file_debug, $line);
        fflush($file_debug);
        fclose($file_debug);
    }

}

?>
```

And my test code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/setting.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/class/class_db_test.php");

$con =  Db::getInstance("db1");
$res = $con->query("db1","SELECT userId from user WHERE userName='test'");

if($res->rowCount() == 1){
    $line = $res->fetchAll();
    $res->closeCursor();
    echo $line[0]['userId'];
}
else{
    echo "0";
}

?>
```

When I change $this to self:: on line 12, 13 and 32, I get theses errors:

```
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for Db::query(), called in /var/www/class/class_db_test.php on line 32 and defined in /var/www/class/class_db_test.php on line 30
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: query in /var/www/class/class_db_test.php on line 31
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: SELECT userId from user WHERE userName='test' in /var/www/class/class_db_test.php on line 32
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /var/www/class/class_db_test.php:32\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/class/class_db_test.php(32): Db->query('SELECT userId f...')\n#1 /var/www/test.php(8): Db->query('db1', 'SELECT userId f...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/class/class_db_test.php on line 32
```

Do you have ideas on how to adapt my code in order make it work on PHP7 ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main things I can see is that you are using `PDOInstances` in two different ways.  It is used for the list of instances of your `Db` class (set in the `getInstance()` static method).  BUT it also seems to be where your trying to store the `PDO` instance for the database (in the constructor).

If you alter the variable you use to store the database (the `Db` class), then this will at least mean you have both pieces of data...

```
private $PDOInstances = array("db1"=>"","db2"=>"");  // Remove static
private static $DbInstances = array("db1"=>"","db2"=>"");


public static function getInstance($db_type) {
    if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("connection","");}

    if(self::$DbInstances[$db_type] == null){
        self::$DbInstances[$db_type] = new self($db_type);
    }
    return self::$DbInstances[$db_type];
}
```

I'm also not sure why when you call

```
$con =  Db::getInstance("db1");
```

you then need to pass the db type to all of the other methods...

```
$res = $con->query("db1","SELECT userId from user WHERE userName='test'");
```

Surely this should be implied by the connection being called with the database type.

If in the constructor you just did (set the `PDOInstances` without the array part)

```
$this->PDOInstances = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST,DB_USER ,DB_PWD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

then all access of the database are done through this...

```
public function query($query){
    if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("read request",$query);}
    return $this->PDOInstances->query($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account Nigel Ren's answer, here is the Db class file modified:

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../setting.php");

class Db {
    private static $debug = 1;
    private static $debugPath = "/tmp/sql_debug.log";
    private $PDOInstances = "";  // Remove static
    private static $DbInstances = array("db1"=>"","db2"=>"");

    private function __construct($db_type){
        switch($db_type) {
            case "db1":
                $this->PDOInstances = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST,DB_USER ,DB_PWD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
                $this->PDOInstances->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            break;
            case "db2":
                $this->PDOInstances = new PDO('mysql:dbname='.DB2_NAME.';host='.DB2_HOST,DB2_USER ,DB2_PWD,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
                $this->PDOInstances->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            break;
        }
    }
    public static function getInstance($db_type) {
        if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("connection","");}

        if(self::$DbInstances[$db_type] == null){
            self::$DbInstances[$db_type] = new self($db_type);
        }
        return self::$DbInstances[$db_type];
    }

    public function query($query){
        if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("read request",$query);}
        return $this->PDOInstances->query($query);
    }

    public function exec($query){
        if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("request",$query);}  
        return $this->PDOInstances->exec($query);
    }

    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->PDOInstances->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function quote($string){
        if(self::$debug == 1){self::sqlDebug("quote",$string);} 
        return $this->PDOInstances->quote($string);
    }

    public static function sqlDebug($_mode,$_query){
        $today = date("m.d.y-H:m:s"); 
        if($_mode == "connection"){
            $line = $today." Connection: '".$_query."'\r\n";
        }
        else if($_mode == "quote"){
            $line = $today." Quote : '".$_query."'\r\n";
        }
        else if($_mode == "request"){
            $line = $today." Request : '".$_query."'\r\n";
        }
        else if($_mode == "read request"){
            $line = $today." Read request : '".$_query."'\r\n";
        }

        $file_debug = fopen(self::$debugPath, "a+");
        fwrite($file_debug, $line);
        fflush($file_debug);
        fclose($file_debug);
    }

}

?>
```

And the test file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/setting.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/class/class_db_test.php");

$con =  Db::getInstance("db1");
$res = $con->query("SELECT userId from user WHERE userName='test'");

if($res->rowCount() == 1){
    $line = $res->fetchAll();
    $res->closeCursor();
    echo $line[0]['userId'];
}
else{
    echo "0";
}

?>
```

Everything is working without PHP Notice/Error.

Thank you !